# How to get all different element tags from root tag using XPath

Tags: c#, xpath, xpathnavigator

I have a following xml file

```
<root>
  <element1>
    <header>header1</header>
    <tag1>tag1</tag1>
    <response>
      <status>success</status>
      <Data>
        <id>d1</id>
        <test>2</test>
      </Data>
      <Beta>
        <betaid>sdsd</betaid>
        <code>123</code>
        <code>ddd</code>
      </Beta>
    </response>
  </element1>
</root>
```

My Question: How to get the first child elements under "Response" tag? i.e staus, data and beta.
Using XPath in C#. Thank you

The .net code i have is here but it does not work.

```
XPathDocument doc= new XPathDocument(XmlReaderdata);
XPathNavigator mes, Nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

foreach(XPathNavigator node in (XPathNodeIterator)Nav.Evaluate("//response/*)
{
            node.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XPath query like this should work:

```
//response/*
```

For example:

```
var xml = @"<root> ... </root>";
using (StringReader stream = new StringReader(xml))
{
    XPathDocument doc= new XPathDocument(stream);
    XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
    XPathNodeIterator itor = (XPathNodeIterator)nav.Evaluate("//response/*");

    foreach(XPathNavigator node in itor)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.Name);
    }
}
```

Produces the output:

```
status
Data
Beta
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but this does not work. Here is my code

Comment: @hss I've provided an example of working code. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `//response`:

DTO:

```
public class Response
{
    public Response()
    {
        Data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        Beta = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    }

    public string Status { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Data { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Beta { get; set; }
}
```

Code:

```
var document = XDocument.Parse(data);

var element = document.XPathSelectElement("//response");

var response = new Response();
response.Status = element.Element("status").Value;

foreach(var dataElement in element.Element("Data").Elements())
{
    response.Data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(dataElement.Name.LocalName, dataElement.Value));
}

foreach(var betaElement in element.Element("Beta").Elements())
{
    response.Beta.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(betaElement.Name.LocalName, betaElement.Value));
}
```

Edit: Partial loading

```
public Response ParseResponse(XPathDocument document)
{
    var navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
    var iterator = navigator.Select("//response");
    iterator.MoveNext();
    var responseDoc = XDocument.Parse(iterator.Current.OuterXml);

    var element = responseDoc.Element("response");

    var response = new Response();
    response.Status = element.Element("status").Value;

    foreach(var dataElement in element.Element("Data").Elements())
    {
        response.Data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(dataElement.Name.LocalName, dataElement.Value));
    }

    foreach(var betaElement in element.Element("Beta").Elements())
    {
        response.Beta.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(betaElement.Name.LocalName, betaElement.Value));
    }

    return response;
}

Response response;

using(var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
{
    var doc = new XPathDocument(reader);
    response = ParseResponse(doc);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the LinqTOXML. Is their a way to do this with XPathDocument? Since my file is quite big and I would like to not load the whole xml data into memory.

Comment: Added some code to load part of the document that is being streamed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the names of the child nodes?
i hope this will help

```
string xmlstring = "<root><element><response><status>Success</status><Data><id>1</id></Data></response></element></root>";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlstring);
        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/root/element/response");
        XmlNodeList children = node.ChildNodes;

        foreach(XmlNode i in children )
        Console.WriteLine(i.Name);
```